# ng-repeat isnt updating model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a nassi-shneidermann-diagram editor.
To display the Diagram in HTML i use nested ng-repeat's

```
<!-- ngRepeat: list in item.container -->
<!-- ngInclude: '/app/ui/templates/strukto/list.xht' -->
<div class="container ng-scope" ng-repeat="list in item.container" ng-include="'/app/ui/templates/strukto/list.xht'">
    <ul class="strukto-element ng-scope" dnd-list="list" ng-class="{ empty: list.length == 0 }">
        <!-- ngRepeat: item in list -->
        <!-- ngInclude: '/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht' -->
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-include="'/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht'">
            <div class="strukto-element anweisung">
                <text class="name ng-binding" data-strukto-editable="true" ng-bind-html="escapeMultiLine(item.text)">Ausgabe Test</text>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: item in list -->
        <!-- ngInclude: '/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht' -->
        <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-include="'/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht'">
            <div class="strukto-element block">
                <div class="section head">
                    <div></div>
                    <text class="name ng-binding" data-strukto-editable="true" ng-bind-html="escapeMultiLine(item.text)">Block</text>
                </div>
                <div class="section body">
                    <div></div>
                    <!-- ngRepeat: list in item.container -->
                    <!-- ngInclude: '/app/ui/templates/strukto/list.xht' -->
                    <div class="container ng-scope" ng-repeat="list in item.container" ng-include="'/app/ui/templates/strukto/list.xht'">
                        <ul class="strukto-element ng-scope" dnd-list="list" ng-class="{ empty: list.length == 0 }">
                            <!-- ngRepeat: item in list -->
                            <!-- ngInclude: '/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht' -->
                            <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-include="'/app/ui/templates/strukto/' + item.type + '.xht'">
                                <div class="strukto-element anweisung">
                                    <text class="name ng-binding" data-strukto-editable="true" ng-bind-html="escapeMultiLine(item.text)">Anweisung</text>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- end ngRepeat: item in list -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end ngRepeat: list in item.container -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: item in list -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is:
This is how its initialized in the Controller

```
$scope.models = {
  editor: [
    { /* Root */
      type: "root" , text: "",
      container: [[ /* Container */
        { type: "anweisung",  text: "Ausgabe Test", }, /* Anweisung:A */
      ]],
    },
  ],
}
```

And this also works

```
/** default.json laden, dannach das Datenmodell abändern */
$http.get('/data/default.json').then(function(res) {
  $scope.models.editor = res.data
  $rootScope.$emit("EditorModelChanged", { model: res.data })
})
```

But if i then add a Button to clear the Array, it doesnt update

```
<button ng-click="models.editor = []">CLEAR</button>
```

I also tried it with an internal function, but it doesnt update ng-refresh

```
  $scope.$on("EditorModelApplyLocal",function(event, data) {
    $timeout(function() {
      //$rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.models.editor.pop() 
      $scope.models.editor = [[ data.model ]]
      $scope.$apply()
      $('.strukto.editor').trigger("create");
      //})
    })
```

There is also an < pre > Element which holds the Model in form of JSON
AND this Updates how it should. So the problem is ng-refresh
It does update ng-refresh if i put it in a $timeout inside the $http.get

```
/** default.json laden, dannach das Datenmodell abändern */
    $http.get('/data/default.json').then(function(res) {
      $scope.models.editor = res.data
      $rootScope.$emit("EditorModelChanged", { model: res.data })
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.models.editor.pop()
        $scope.$apply()
        $('.strukto.editor').trigger("create");
        //})
        if (debugTerm) debugTerm.printDebug($scope.namespace,"End Single Test removing")
      },4000)
    })
```

If you want to test this by yourself: just visit https://strukto5.cf/#/editor

The Question is:
Is there any way to solve this Problem?

Comment: some jsfiddle with an actual working exmaple would be great. I don't see at what place you actually use the $scope.models variable in the template. And you have a pretty weird data flow. I recommend not to use ng-includes on ng-repeats and don't use custom html inside ng-includes tag. Maybe it makes sense to extract some logic into separate components/directives

Answer (score 0):

Your question is particularly hard to read to see where the error is, but I suspect your problem is that each ng-repeat has its own scope.

To give an isolated example:

```
<div init="foo = 1">
    <h1>{{foo}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="bar in barCollection">
        <button ng-click="foo = bar">set foo = bar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

on the button click, the h1 is still going to say 1.

At a minimum you would need to replace the button with:

```
        <button ng-click="$parent.foo = bar">set foo = bar</button>
```

There are better ways of handling data than this though - but you will need to choose a method which fits your solution.